# Back button also validates the html form like the submit button

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I created HTML form which has two buttons, one for calling java script for form validations and the other one back to the previous page, the two buttons act as submit and validate the inputs.
Here is the code for the form and the button:

```
<form id = "myform" method="post" action="SearchForCustomer"         onsubmit="return validateForm()">
<input type="submit"  value="Search"  style="width: 100%;" onclick="toggleTable();" />
<input type="button"  value="back" style="width: 100%;" onclick="document.forms[0].action = 'homePage.jsp'; return true;"  />
</form>
```

I want the back button to only back whatever the validations was, any suggestions?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually i didnt get your question but why to use input[type=submit] to goto any page (or back)?

Comment: <input type="button"  value="back" style="width: 100%;" onclick="window.location.href = 'homePage.jsp'; return true;"  /> or <button type="button"  style="width: 100%;" onclick="window.location.href = 'homePage.jsp'; return true;"  />back</button>

Comment: I posted it by fault, I tried type = "button" and it does't work.

Comment: try <button type="button" style="width: 100%;" onclick="window.location.href = 'homePage.jsp'; return true;" />back</button>

Comment: Welcome, but avoid using button and use A tag instead

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
<input type="button"...
```

type="submit" will submit form in either case.

Answer (score 0):

You have two buttons of type submit. Have only 1.

```
<form id = "myform" method="post" action="SearchForCustomer" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
    <input type="submit" name = "searchButton" id = "searchButton"  value="Search"  style="width: 100%;" onclick="toggleTable();" />
    <input type="button"  value="back" style="width: 100%;" onclick="document.forms[0].action = 'homePage.jsp'; return true;"  />
</form>
```